# Broadcastreceiver can be called from ADP but not other apps

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wear-os, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver I am using to display some notification. I can call it and have it be correctly triggered using ADB. But calling it from within another app does nothing.

The receiver does live in/on a Android Wear app/device.

Receiver

`<receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="site.com.app.SHOW_NOTIFICATION" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>`

Call from ADB

```
./adb -s SERIAL shell am broadcast -a site.com.app.SHOW_NOTIFICATION
```

Call from App

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("site.com.app.SHOW_NOTIFICATION");
i.putExtra("contentText", "Some Text");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

I'm not sure why it would work from ADB but not from another App, any ideas?

Comment: On which device with which OS version are you testing? For example, Huawei: Your broadcastreceiver will not receiving anything in the sleep mode until you are enabling autostart in the system. I don´t know if other suppliers do some shit like this, but it´s possible that your app is stopped. As long as you keep it connected to your IDE, it won´t get stopped, so it´s receiving the broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exact your code but you can try below code which I have made for you.

```
**Second Application**

    package com.example.jiteshmohite.callingbroadcast;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private Button button;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    lunchExportedBroadcast();
                }
            });
        }
            private void lunchExportedBroadcast() {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("com.example.exportedreceiver");
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.jiteshmohite.callingbroadcast.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:text="Call Broadcast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>

**First Application who register broadcast**

    public class ExportedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public ExportedReceiver() {`enter code here`
            // empty constr
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // showing toast whenever any external application call these receiver.
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "ExportedReceiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

**Register receiver in First Application**

    <receiver android:name=".receiver.ExportedReceiver">
                <intent-filter >
                    <action  android:name="com.example.exportedreceiver"></action>
                </intent-filter>

            </receiver>
```